# Negative and incorrect values when reading raster files using PySheds library

Tags: python, raster

I am working with the pysheds library to read and process raster files. I encountered an issue when I read some of the raster files, as they produce negative and incorrect values. Here is the code I am using:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from pysheds.grid import Grid

grid = Grid.from_raster('/content/dem_dig.tif')
dem = grid.read_raster('/content/dem_dig.tif')
```

The code seems to work fine, but when I print the dem variable, it shows the following output:

```
[[ 3.9230000e+01  3.8570000e+01  3.8020000e+01 ... -3.4028235e+38  -3.4028235e+38 -3.4028235e+38]
 [ 3.9230000e+01  3.8570000e+01  3.8020000e+01 ... -3.4028235e+38  -3.4028235e+38 -3.4028235e+38]
 [ 4.0310001e+01  3.9490002e+01  3.8880001e+01 ... -3.4028235e+38  -3.4028235e+38 -3.4028235e+38]
 ...
 [-3.4028235e+38 -3.4028235e+38 -3.4028235e+38 ... -3.4028235e+38  -3.4028235e+38 -3.4028235e+38]
 [-3.4028235e+38 -3.4028235e+38 -3.4028235e+38 ... -3.4028235e+38  -3.4028235e+38 -3.4028235e+38]
 [-3.4028235e+38 -3.4028235e+38 -3.4028235e+38 ... -3.4028235e+38  -3.4028235e+38 -3.4028235e+38]]
```

It's important to note that this issue only occurs with some raster files, not all of them. When I open the problematic raster files in QGIS, I don't see these negative and wrong values. Unfortunately, the raster files I need for my work are among the ones with this issue.

Could anyone provide some guidance on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?

I am trying to calculate this hydrological distance to the outlet of each cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative values you see are nodata which may be set on your input DEM.

If you want to work only on the produced file, you can threshold your raster, set the values under the threshold (i.e. -1e20) to a nodata value (i.e. -9999 for float data) and assign -9999 to the nodata of your output raster.